# How to sort the output of "grep -l" chronologically by newest modification date last?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I'm using the -l flag with grep to just print the matching file names.

I want to then list the results (files) in ascending order i.e. newest last.

Obviously

```
grep -l <pattern> *.txt | ls -rt
```

is not what I need, since the *ls -lrt* merely outputs *all* files.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try:

```
ls -rt *.txt | xargs grep -l <pattern>
```

We first use `ls` to list `*.txt` files and sort them by modification time (newest last), then for each entry run them through `grep` so we only print out files that contain the pattern.

Comment: Make sure you `cd` into the directory, beacuse `grep` will look for filenames in the **current working directory**.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way

```
grep -l <pattern> *.txt | xargs ls -ltr --time-style="+%Y%m%d_%H%M"
```

For example

```
$ grep -l argparse * | xargs ls -ltr --time-style="+%Y%m%d_%H%M"
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raju 197121   979 20171030_2323 list_dep.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raju 197121 14329 20180129_2216 grep_installed.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raju 197121  7517 20180129_2216 popsort.py
```

To just list the files without timestamps etc.,

```
grep -l <pattern> * | xargs ls -1tr
```

For example

```
$ grep -l argparse * | xargs ls -1tr
list_dep.py
grep_installed.py
popsort.py
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but thought of adding my suggestion for someone who is searching for the same..

`for i in $(ls -rt *.txt); do grep <pattern> $i; done`