# How to sort the output of recursive “grep -lr” chronologically by newest modification date last?

Tags: grep, ls

I want to get a list of all files, in the current directory or any subdirectory, containing a certain string sorted by modification date.

I am having trouble getting the answer to

[How to sort the output of "grep -l" chronologically by newest modification date last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392526/how-to-sort-the-output-of-grep-l-chronologically-by-newest-modification-date)

to work for the purpose of a recursive grep search. How do I obtain such a ordered list such that all files that would be found by `grep -lr` are really included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file names don't contain newlines:

```
find dir -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\n' | sort | cut -f2- | xargs grep -l whatever
```

More robustly using GNU versions of the tools to deal with dir/file names containing exoctic characters:

```
find dir -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | sort -z | cut -z -f2- | xargs -0 grep -l whatever
```

Comment: `-printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS\t%p\n"` works for sorting as well with the added benefit of being human readable if you need to see the date